# Javascript tips: 2 to the power of x multiplied by n

Tags: code-golf, tips, javascript

I'm new to ES6 and code-golfing. Here's the original function:

```js
function puzzle(n, x) {
  return n * Math.pow(2, x);
}
```

And here's what I have so far:

```
let puzzle=(n,x)=>n*2<<(x-1)
```

But the solution requires lesser characters. I went through the 'Code Golfing with ES6' thread, but couldn't find a better way.
Any help/links would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try `n<<x`.

Comment: FYI there isn't much point in a Stack Snippet if you aren't going to build it into some HTML

Comment: Ah. That did it :)
@βετѧΛєҫαγ Point noted.

Answer (score 11):

### 17 bytes:

```
puzzle=n=>x=>n<<x
```

This uses the fact that `2 * 2^n` = `2^(n + 1)`. Also, by our rules, using [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) instead of taking multiple arguments the usual way [is allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8427/34543). Also, I don't think the `let` is needed.